# What is the commonly used data source for iOS application?

Tags: ios, sql-server, database, swift2

What is the best and commonly used datasource for an iOS Application?
I am a .NET developer and want to use mssql server for database. Any suggestion on that? webservices, xml providers, etc...

Comment: for external, i'll recommend to use WebServices to store in your database, for internal there is Core Data. (very smart Framework)

Comment: Just anything you'd use for any other application :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just about every mobile app that deals with databases uses [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/).  There are many tutorials on it.

Answer (score 4):

The CoreData Framework, which is the iOS DeFacto DataStore utilises SQLite. Lot's of support and tutorials on it online.